# Regex: replace single characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to replace "\n" characters to " " if it's standing alone.

I have a string like:
**"Hello\n Stack\n\n\nover\nflow"**

And it should be replaced with:
**"Hello  Stack\n\n\nover flow"**

I've tried on ruby something like this:

```
> "Hello\n Stack\n\n\nover\nflow".gsub(/\n(?![\n])/, " ")
=> "Hello  Stack\n\n over flow"
```

But it saves an extra "\n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im guessing you need something like `/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/`. To check that there is no `\n` before or after the matching one.

Thanks @JohnySkovdal for the correction

Comment: Don't you mean `(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)` then? :)

Comment: @JohnySkovdal I have no idea :P I just followed from his example and tried to fix the logical error. Please feel free and edit it if you like

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to make Expresso treat '\n' as a non-literal, in order to test it. ^^ But yeah `?<!` is to match and exclude prefixes, while `?!` is for suffixes.

Comment: It worked (tested it with `\r\n` instead which is default in Expresso for returns). Nicely spotted that neither pre nor postfix must be `\n`. :)

Comment: @JohnySkovdal Thanks you! Works great. I didn't know about lookbehind assertions :)