# Regular Expression: How to Combin Lookahead and Lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of comma-delimited characters that I'm splitting. Some of these characters, though, could be commas. For example:

`test = "a,b,c,d,,,e,f,g"`

I know that `(?<!,),` is the regular expression for "any commas not preceded by a comma", and `,(?!,)` is the regular expression for "any comma followed by a comma". Could someone point me in the right direction and show me how to combine these two. The desired output is:

```
a  
b  
c  
d  
,  
e  
f  
g
```

The program is in Java, so if someone knows a function specific to Java, that works, too.

Comment: Could you not just search for `,,,` and replace it with `,<REPLACE ME>,` and then search for `<REPLACE ME>` after splitting?

Comment: How would you like to split `"a,b,c,d,,,,,e,f,g"`? Should it be `a b c d , , e f g`?

Comment: +1 @Pshemo. And, even more interesting, what should happen with `"a,b,c,d,,,,e,f,g"`?

Comment: @Bergi Output will probably look like this `a b c d , ,e f g` but indeed interesting input. Other option is throwing exception/returning null/destroying computer of person who produced that input.

Comment: I solved it. Read my solution.

Comment: As I said, this is a string, but it's made up of comma-delimited single characters. As such, `a,b,c,d,,,,e,f,g"` wouldn't be in there.

Comment: @Adam_G In your question there is no info about uniqueness of characters. Is it possible that input String will contain few same characters like `a,a,b`? If so shouldn't we think of possibility of few comas next to each other also separated with comas like `a,,,,,b`? What then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `,` only if there is no `,` before or after it .

```
    String str = "a,b,c,d,,,e,f,g";
    String regex = "(?<!,),|,(?!,)";

    for(String s : str.split(regex)) {            
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> a
> b
> c
> d
> ,
> e
> f
> g
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize you could combine two regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue tackled in [Regex: replace single characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875084/regex-replace-single-characters)

Just merging the  two regexes that you have, as `(?<!,),(?!,)` should do the trick, unless there are subtle differences between ruby and Java in this area.

If you want to delete all single `,` and replace `,,,` with `,` specifically, then you could run search and delete the matched chars from `(?<!,)?,(?!,)` twice.

Comment: Have you tested it? Does that really work in Ruby? Even Rubular (engineered by Ruby) doesn't match that comma: http://rubular.com/r/1B8ohv7mUT

Comment: @BalusC Your link seems to indicate it works perfectly, remember the OP wants to check for single `,` i.e `!,` `,` `!,`

Comment: It results in `a`, `b`, `c`, `d,,,e`, `f` and `g`. Note the `d,,,e` part. The OP want to have it as `d`, `, ` and `e`.

Comment: @BalusC ah yes, I miss read the intent of the question. In that case running the search and replace twice with (?<!,)?,(?!,) should work in this specific case.

Comment: I know this is very old, but this answer contributed to a misunderstanding I had about a negative lookbehind and lookahead. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001793/negative-lookbehind-followed-by-negative-lookahead

Answer (score 1):

You could use `(.)(?:,|$)` instead of lookahead/lookbehind.

`(?:,|$)` will match the commas in between or the end of line for the last character, while `(.)` will capture the character.

Obviously, this will work only if you are matching against a regex expression, not if you are using the expression on the String's `split` method; in that case you should do as you suggested, using `^(?<=,),^(?!=,)`.

Answer (score 0):

the following will find a character followed by a comma and then remove the final comma by only taking the first character:

```
        String test = "a,b,c,d,,,e,f,g";
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(".,|.$");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(test);
        while(m.find() ){                    
            System.out.println(m.group().charAt(0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for data `"a,b,c,d,,,,,e,f,g"` split should look like `a b c d , , e f g` you could find pair of comas and place some special mark between them. This way you will know that coma with that special mark after it need to be removed, but coma with special mark before it need to stay. Code based on that idea can look like

```
String data = "a,b,c,d,,,,,e,f,g";
data = data.replace(",,", ",XspecialSplitX,");

String[] tokens = data.split(",XspecialSplitX|(?<!XspecialSplitX),");
for (String s : tokens)
    System.out.print(s+" ");
```

Output: `a b c d , , e f g`

---

Faster and easier way without regex.
If your string contains only **single** characters separated with comas then all wanted characters will have even indexes and separating comas odd. In this case all you need to do is iterate over all even indexes like this

```
char[] data="a,b,c,d,,,e,f,g".toCharArray();
for(int i=0; i<data.length; i+=2)
    System.out.println(data[i]);
```